# Resuming drawing a CAShapeLayer when view reenters foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

```
  func makeACircle(circle: UIView, stokeStart: Double, duration: Double){


        var progressCircle = CAShapeLayer();

        let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2);
        let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2

        var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true    );

        progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ();
        progressCircle.path = circlePath.cgPath;
        progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor;
        progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor;
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 10;
        progressCircle.strokeStart = 0;
        progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1;
        progressCircle.borderWidth = 1
        progressCircle.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle);
       // progressCircle.clipsToBounds = false
        self.view.addSubview(circle)

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        // Set the animation duration appropriately
        animation.duration = duration

        // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
        animation.fromValue = stokeStart
        animation.toValue = 1

        // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

        // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
        // right value when the animation ends.
        progressCircle.strokeEnd = 1.0

        // Do the actual animation
        progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")

    }
```

I'm drawing circles in with the above code. It draws a circle around buttons on the screen that represent time that's passed since the creation of the button. This code works, but when I go to the homescreen and come back, all of the circles on the screen are completely filled in regardless of how much time was left. If within the app I then switch to another page and then come back, it fixes it.

I'm calling makeACircle from within this firebase query

```
 currentUserRef?.child("invitedToPosts").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: cutoff).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
```

Once I have enough information about a button to be made, I make the button, then call the makeACircle.

Any ideas on how to prevent the circles from not appearing as if they've reached the strokeEnd when I load in from the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

When you pause the animation,

- Look at the [presentation layer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentation) and save its `strokeEnd`.
- You need to stop the animation, do so. You may want to set the `strokeEnd` from the presentation layer's value to avoid any jarring changes.
- See how much time has elapsed since you started the animation (e.g. compare `CACurrentMediaTime()` when you paused vs the value when you started the animation) in order to figure out how much time is remaining in the animation.

Then when you re-present the layer, you now have the `fromValue` for the `strokeEnd` and what the remaining `duration` is.

Another thing that can be useful is to set the `delegate` of the animation and then use `animationDidStop` to `nil` your "in progress" state variables if the animation successfully finishes (i.e. if `finished` is true).